# ReactJS material-ui use the class `Mui-disabled` for read-only components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm building a new component from `TextField` and I need to apply the same style for text fields with the `readOnly` than `disabled` property.

So, I was trying to use the property `className` but it does not work.

```
// some logic here ..

<TextField
    {...props}
    className={readOnly ? 'Mui-disabled' : undefined}
 />
```

So, I also tried to use the `classses` prop, but I don't know how to get the current config from the disabled class.

Comment: Try the prop `classes` instead of `className`. https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/

Comment: @sallf as I mentioned in my question, I tried to use `classes` prop, but I don't know how to get the style from `Mui-disabled`. Do you have a suggestion for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use the `disabled` property, Material-UI places the `Mui-disabled` class on many different elements. To get the equivalent look, you need to add it to all the same elements.

Below is an example of how to do this. In addition to adding the `Mui-disabled` class, it is also necessary to override the ["focused" styling](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.5.0/packages/material-ui/src/Input/Input.js#L30) of the underline (handled via the `:after` pseudo-class).

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const disabledClassNameProps = { className: "Mui-disabled" };
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => {
  const light = theme.palette.type === "light";
  const bottomLineColor = light
    ? "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.42)"
    : "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)";
  return {
    underline: {
      "&.Mui-disabled:after": {
        borderBottom: `1px dotted ${bottomLineColor}`,
        transform: "scaleX(0)"
      }
    }
  };
});
function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField
        {...disabledClassNameProps}
        inputProps={{ readOnly: true }}
        InputProps={{ ...disabledClassNameProps, classes }}
        InputLabelProps={disabledClassNameProps}
        FormHelperTextProps={disabledClassNameProps}
        label="Test Disabled Look"
        defaultValue="Some Text"
        helperText="Helper Text"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit TextField readOnly looking disabled]

Related answers:

- [Altering multiple component roots for MUI Textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57917743/altering-multiple-component-roots-for-mui-textfield/57926379#57926379)
- [How can I remove the underline of TextField from Material-UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57914368/how-can-i-remove-the-underline-of-textfield-from-material-ui/57915357#57915357)
- [How do I custom style the underline of Material-UI without using theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56023814/how-do-i-custom-style-the-underline-of-material-ui-without-using-theme/56026253#56026253)

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I found that the `InputProps` also have the `className` property. The following worked for me:

```
<TextField
    {...props}
    inputProps={{
        readOnly,
    }}
    InputProps={{
        className: (readOnly) ? 'Mui-disabled' : undefined,
    }}
/>
```

To see all the properties you can look [here](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/).

Comment: If you use helper text or labels this will not be sufficient to get the disabled look. Also if you click on the input the underline will still change color (unless you're using the filled or outlined variant).

Answer (score -2):

You need to use classes on TextField

```
<TextField
 {...props}
 classes={readOnly ? { root: 'Mui-disabled' } : {}}
/>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tested this approach here, but it does not work https://codesandbox.io/s/usage-7f7y9